# Removing duplicates from the list with different ways

Tags: java, collections

I have an class called employee that is the pojo , and I have created the list of this pojo type means of employee type..Now I want to remove the duplicates from the list , Please advise what are the various ways to achieve that..

```
class Emp implements Comparable
{
      String name,job;
      int salary;
      public Emp(String n,String j,int sal)
      {
         name=n;
         job=j;
         salary=sal;
       }
      public void display()
      {
        System.out.println(name+"\t"+job+"\t"+salary);
       }
      public boolean equals(Object o)
      {
          Emp p=(Emp)o;
          return this.name.equals(p.name)&&this.job.equals(p.job)           &&this.salary==p.salary;
       }
       public int hashCode()
       {
          return name.hashCode()+job.hashCode()+salary;
       }  
       public int compareTo(Object o)
       {
          Emp e=(Emp)o;
          return this.name.compareTo(e.name);
           //return this.job.compareTo(e.job);
          // return this.salary-e.salary;

        }
}
```

and here is my list of employee type..

```
import java.util.*;
class EmpListDemo
{
      public static void main(String arg[])
      {
          ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
          list.add(new Emp("Ram","Trainer",34000));
          list.add(new Emp("Sachin","Programmer",24000));
          list.add(new Emp("Priyanka","Manager",54000));
          list.add(1,new Emp("Ravi","Administrator",44000));
                 list.add(new Emp("Ram","Trainer",34000));
          list.add(new Emp("Anupam","Programmer",34000));
list.add(new Emp("Sachin","Programmer",24000));
          list.add(new Emp("Sachin","Team Leader",54000));
          System.out.println("There are "+list.size()+" elements in the list.");
          System.out.println("Content of list are : ");
          ListIterator itr=list.listIterator();
          while(itr.hasNext())
          {
            Emp e=(Emp)itr.next();  
            e.display();
          }   

}
}
```

Comment: ... and it's probably homework.

Comment: Post on SO, Let it boil for a few minutes. Collect answers.
Please read the [F.A.Q](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) before posting questions

Answer (score 3):

To remove duplicate elements from an array list you should consider using a hash set b/c they do not allow duplicates.

```
// Declare your reference variables
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
HashSet hashSet = new HashSet();

// Put all list elements into hashset
hashSet.addAll(list);
list.clear();
list.addAll(hashSet);
```

Comment: Nice, I'm not sure whether the objects in the list need to implement an interface and/or equals for this to work, could you add some clarification regarding those?

Comment: @G.Bach have to implement equals() and hashCode() for this to work

Comment: Couldn't this become a problem though? If he's not aware of how to remove duplicates, implementing hashCode() correctly should be a little bit out of his league, no?

Comment: @Keith Randall: I doubt his hashCode is guaranteed to produce distinct hashes for unequal objects. While that isn't necessary according to the specification of hashCode(), it could mess up the elimination since it could lead to objects without duplicates being eliminated. I can only assume that implementation was provided for his homework, but that doesn't change the fact that unequal objects need to be assigned distinct hashCodes for his purposes. I think that should be pointed out in case this is not homework and is actually supposed to go into production code.

Comment: @G.Bach: it is *not* necessary that unequal objects produce unequal hashes.  You should read up on how hashtables work.  Unequal objects with the same hash might slow the algorithm down, but it will never allow a duplicate to be missed or incorrectly identified.

Comment: @KeithRandall: Assume his list is list = {A, A, B} and that A.hashCode() == B.hashCode(). The way I understand it, hashSet.addAll(list), assuming it adds the elements in the order I gave, would make the hashSet = {A}, no?

Comment: @G.Bach: No.  Try it.  You clearly don't understand hashtables.

Comment: @KeithRandall: My mistake, I did mix things up. I would have appreciated a less patronizing tone though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LinkedHashSet to preserve elements order, something like this:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
// list initialization

LinkedHashSet set = new LinkedHashSet();
set.addAll(list);
list.clear();
list.addAll(set);
```

Answer (score 1):

Three ways come to mind instantly:

- iterate through the list for each element, check against all other elements and remove the other one on collision. Runtime is in O(n^2)
- sort the list, iterate through it, keeping track of the current item A; remove subsequent items until there is an item B != A; go on until end of list. Runtime is sorting + iteration, so something between O(n log n) and O (n^2)
- put your items into some sort of hashing data structure, empty your list and take only a single item from the hash structure for each hash value that will be reinserted into your list. Runtime should be O(n) if done correctly

Answer (score 1):

**1.** When the **uniqueness** is important, then use `Set`.

**2.** I will advice you to use the class `HashSet`, **but if along with Uniqueness , Sorting is also important, then use** `TreeSet` which **implements** `SortedSet` Interface, which further extends `Collection` Interface.

**3.** Moreover you can Sort the `TreeSet` in **more than one ways...by using**`Comparator` **Interface.**