# Research on removal of duplicate elements

Tags: java, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing duplicates from the list with different ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763362/removing-duplicates-from-the-list-with-different-ways)

I was doing a research and find this below way to remove the duplicates from the list..but please advise is there are any other ways too as I was doing research on this and I want to explore other ways too within collection that will be a great..what I am more intrested in my research is new jdk 1.5 have some thing new to offer with this context

```
class Emp //implements Comparable
{
      String name,job;
      int salary;
      public Emp(String n,String j,int sal)
      {
         name=n;
         job=j;
         salary=sal;
       }
      public void display()
      {
        System.out.println(name+"\t"+job+"\t"+salary);
       }
     public boolean equals(Object o)
      {

         Emp p=(Emp)o;
          return this.name.equals(p.name)&&this.job.equals(p.job) &&this.salary==p.salary;
       }
     public int hashCode()
       {
          return name.hashCode()+job.hashCode()+salary;
       }


      /* public int compareTo(Object o)
       {
          Emp e=(Emp)o;
          return this.name.compareTo(e.name);
           //return this.job.compareTo(e.job);
        //   return this.salary-e.salary;

        }*/
}
```

and the final class will be ...

```
 class EmpListDemo
    {
          public static void main(String arg[])
          {
              List  list=new ArrayList ();
              list.add(new Emp("Ram","Trainer",34000));
              list.add(new Emp("Sachin","Programmer",24000));
              list.add(new Emp("Ram","Trainer",34000));
              list.add(new Emp("Priyanka","Manager",54000));
              list.add(1,new Emp("Ravi","Administrator",44000));
              list.add(new Emp("Anupam","Programmer",34000));
              list.add(new Emp("Priyanka","Manager",54000));
              list.add(new Emp("Sachin","Team Leader",54000));
              System.out.println("There are "+list.size()+" elements in the list.");



              System.out.println("Content of list are : ");
              ListIterator itr1=list.listIterator();
              while(itr1.hasNext())
              {
                Emp e=(Emp)itr1.next();  
                e.display();
              }           

//Removing duplicates from the list
          Set hs = new HashSet();
          hs.addAll(list);
          list.clear();
          list.addAll(hs);
          System.out.println("******************************");
          System.out.println("There are "+hs.size()+" elements in the set.");
          System.out.println("Contents after modification : ");
          Iterator itr=list.iterator();
          while(itr.hasNext())
          {
            Emp e=(Emp)itr.next();  
            e.display();
          }   




              }
    }
```

Comment: If your container needs to have no duplicates, why do you `List` and not a `HashSet`? You need to use the data structure most fit for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `HashSet`:

```
class EmpListDemo
{
  public static void main(String arg[])
  {
      Set list = new HashSet();
      list.add(new Emp("Ram","Trainer",34000));
      list.add(new Emp("Sachin","Programmer",24000));
      list.add(new Emp("Ram","Trainer",34000));
      list.add(new Emp("Priyanka","Manager",54000));
      list.add(new Emp("Ravi","Administrator",44000));
      list.add(new Emp("Anupam","Programmer",34000));
      list.add(new Emp("Priyanka","Manager",54000));
      list.add(new Emp("Sachin","Team Leader",54000));
      System.out.println("There are "+list.size()+" elements in the list.");



      System.out.println("Content of list are : ");
      ListIterator itr1=list.listIterator();
      while(itr1.hasNext())
      {
        Emp e=(Emp)itr1.next();  
        e.display();
      }           

      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use any Implementation of `Set` Brother..
Rather than allowing duplicates and then later removing it ;
prevent your data structure from even allowing them...